# StringDef in pure java module?

Tags: java, android, gradle, annotations

Using gradle, I have two modules, `:android` and `:core`, with `:android` containing the android-specific stuff and `:core` containing all the business logic.

I had a bunch of enum values, so naturally, I converted them to StringDef. Problem is that I can't seem to use Support-Annotations in my `:core`-module, gradle complains that it can't resolve `com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1`

What can I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution after digging around a bit. In your project-level build.gradle, you need to add your sdk-path to repositories.

It ends ups looking like this

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url '<your-SDK-path>/extras/android/m2repository' }
  }
}
```